# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'a', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'b'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            var model = db.Posts.ToList();
            int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int pageSize = 10;
            return View(model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));}
```

in the "index" I have a box with tags, it takes the name of the tag and goes into the "Tag"

```
(@foreach (Webtion8.Models.Tag tag in item.Tags){
        <span><a href="@Href("~/Post/Tags/"+tag.Name)">@tag.Name</a></span>}):


@model PagedList.IPagedList<Webtion8.Models.Post>
@using PagedList.Mvc
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("/Content/PagedList.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {<tr>
        <td>
            post: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            date: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            avtor: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Avtor)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="4"> tegs:
    @foreach (Webtion8.Models.Tag tag in item.Tags)
    {
        <span><a href="@Href("~/Post/Tags/"+tag.Name)">@tag.Name</a></span>
    }
    </td></tr>

    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
    }</table>

<div style="text-align: center;">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }),
    new PagedListRenderOptions {
        LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<<",
        LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "<",
        LinkToNextPageFormat = ">",
        LinkToLastPageFormat = ">>" })
</div>
```

they go to here

```
public ActionResult Tags(string id) 
            {   Tag tag = GetTag(id);
                return View("Index", tag.Posts);}
```

and here start the problem I can not solve. In theory this code should return the page index with a sample blog entries by tag on which we clicked. But the program gives an error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Webtion8.Models.Post]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[Webtion8.Models.Post]'.
```

and

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Webtion8.Models.Post]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[Webtion8.Models.Post]'.`
```

Please explain to me where I'm wrong, because the other pages I have not found an answer.

Comment: Can you post the `ToPagedList` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is connected with the fact that your view is strongly typed to `IPagedList<Post>`

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Webtion8.Models.Post>
```

whereas you try to pass a `HashSet of Posts` as a result of your `Tags` action.

So instead of this:

```
public ActionResult Tags(string id) 
{   
      Tag tag = GetTag(id);
       return View("Index", tag.Posts);
}
```

You should do this:

```
public ActionResult Tags(string id) 
{   
     Tag tag = GetTag(id);
     //TODO define pageNumber and pageSize or pass them as parameters to your action method
     return View("Index",tag.Posts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: In my case it was because i had 2 index actions, one for get and other for post. My form's method post was sending data to post-index so the data was not handled correctly.